# P: Límitar una operación o variable para que solo pueda marcar valores positivos

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo una función para entregar cambios de moneda por ejemplo de COP a USD, y tengo la condición de entregar la menor cantidad de billetes o monedas posibles. Ahora mismo estoy intentando calcular cuantos billetes o monedas de cada demonicación debo entregar de la siguiente manera:

```
  USDcien=math.floor(dolaresACambiar%100)
  USDcincuenta=math.floor((dolaresACambiar-USDcien*100)%50)
  USDveinte=math.floor((dolaresACambiar-(USDcien*100USD+cincuenta*50))%20)
  USDdiez=math.floor((dolaresACambiar-(USDcien*100USD+cincuenta*50+USDveinte*20))%10)
  USDcinco=math.floor((dolaresACambiardolaresACambiar-(USDcien*100USD+cincuenta*50+USDveinte*20+USDdiez*10))%5)
  USDuno=math.floor((dolaresACambiardolaresACambiar-(USDcien*100USD+cincuenta*50+USDveinte*20+USDdiez*10+USDcinco*5))%1)
  half=math.floor((dolaresACambiardolaresACambiar-(USDcien*100USD+cincuenta*50+USDveinte*20+USDdiez*10+USDcinco*5+USDuno))%0.5)
  dime=math.floor((dolaresACambiardolaresACambiar-(USDcien*100USD+cincuenta*50+USDveinte*20+USDdiez*10+USDcinco*5+USDuno+half*0.5))%0.1)
  centavo=math.floor((dolaresACambiardolaresACambiar-(USDcien*100USD+cincuenta*50+USDveinte*20+USDdiez*10+USDcinco*5+USDuno+half*0.5+dime*0,1))%0.01)
```

Por el momento creo que va bien, pero es posible que algunos valores se vuelvan negativos en el proceso y se dañe todo. Por lo cual mi duda es la siguiente ¿Existe alguna manera (que no sea por condicionales ya que serían muchos) de hacer que si el valor USD cualquiera es menor a 0, este tome el valor de 0? Creo haber visto una función llamada max que me limita el rango de la función pero no llegué a entenderla muy bien. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Para este caso se usa el patrón

```
valor_positivo = max(0, valor_calculado)
```

Si el `valor_calculado` es menor que cero, la función `max` retorna cero. En caso contrario, retorna `valor_calculado`.

Igualmente para el caso contrario, cuando el valor no deba exceder un cierto límite, se usa `min`:

```
valor_valido = min(valor_limite, valor_calculado)
```

Answer (score 1):

la funcion max(valor1,valor2) te devuelve el valor maximo,esto te sirve para lo que quieres hacer simplemente haz lo siguiente con cada fila

`USDcien=max(0,  math.floor(dolaresACambiar%100)  )` esto hara que si el resultado de `math.floor(dolaresACambiar%100)` es negativo el valor que tome USDcien sea el 0